# Avoid traffic toward unassigned ip address

Tags: routing

In my environment job, we assign IP public segments to our customers. For example, I am using a /29 public segment. If the customer is only using two IP addresses, when I send a ping to the other IPs that the customer isn't using, I receive a `TTL:Expired in transit` message. This effect could elevate the CPU consumption.

Do you know any way to avoid this useless traffic?

We have an Arbor appliance and we use Cisco (90%) and Huawei (10%) devices.

Comment: this isn't a security question but a router config question

Comment: the devices would have to know that there *wasn't* an active device on the IP - I'm not sure how you would determine that

Comment: I have been looking for a possible answer but i didn't find a way to detect free ip addresses and avoid this traffic, imaybe is there a way "to advise" about that our network?

Comment: You could try asking this question on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com. If you do, consider adding some more details on the network topology and avoid asking questions which lead to resource recommendations, since those are off topic.